# How to get Popup window in struts2 without using javascript code

Tags: struts2

How to get an pop up window in a struts2 program , I am not using any JavaScript code. Is it possible to get a pop up window using Struts2 code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a popup box then you could use javascript to do it. Also its WAY EASIER to do it using javascript.

It would be something like this -

```
alert("This text will be displayed in the alert box!");
```

As with struts2 , you could use javascript by adding the javascript inside the `<script>` tag.

Hope this helps!
Cheers :)

Comment: Is there any chance to have a pop up window without using JavaScript .

Comment: I got it using JavaScript